# Mongodb is not running

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed mongodb in my computer. But whenever I try to launch it, it's not running. I have entered command , as "mongo" to start the mongodb, which shows following resuts, but the application is not opening.

Any one having any idea how can I fix this? Please share it. Thanx!

[image: Snippet of the response]

Environment: Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are warnings that appear at the first `mongo` start. Don't worry to much about them.

Since the process is still running and you got the small `>` character there, that means you successfully connected to the MongoDB server.

`mongod` is the MongoDB server (you can check if it's running by running `ps aux | grep mongod`) and the `mongo` cli tool is a cli client connecting to the server. Here you can run commands.

For example, create your first document:

```
use myDatabase
db.people.insert({ name: "Rhea" })
db.people.find()
```

---

In conclusion, both the MongoDB server and client are running but you got a few warnings that only appear the first time when you run `mongo`.

Comment: But the GUI s not opening. why? i need the interface to import the existing files that I have.

Comment: @rhea `mongo` is a command line tool. There is no UI. To import the files you can use the command line. If you really want a GUI, [check this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/196136/148451). I recommend the command line way, because on a real server you don't want to install GUI programs, most probably.

Comment: oh okay thanx for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Initially in one terminal write mongod.
Then on another terminal : mongo .

The first one will start the mongo server.
The second one will start the interpreter.
You can try various commands in the interpreter.